# Libgdx Rectangle detect Touch

Tags: java, onclick, libgdx, touch, rectangles

I want to detect if the user clicks a llama and increase the money but it won't work(nothing happens if I click the (moving) llama). I didn't find a solution for this in the internet.

I added this in render():

```
    if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){

        for (Lama lama : lamas) {
            if(lama.lamarect.contains(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getX())){
                money+=100;
            }else{
                Gdx.app.setLogLevel(Application.LOG_DEBUG);
                Gdx.app.debug("POSITION", "X touched: " + Gdx.input.getX() + " Y touched: " + Gdx.input.getY());

            }
        }

    }
```

**EDIT:**

```
@Override
public void create() {
spawnLama();
textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("data/lamination.pack"));
    animation = new Animation(1/15f, textureAtlas.getRegions());
camera = new OrthographicCamera(1280, 720);
```

...

```
private void spawnLama() {

    Lama lama = new Lama();

    lama.x = MathUtils.random(-1000, -200);
    lama.y = MathUtils.random(-350, 100);
    lama.speedx = MathUtils.random(-5, 5);
    if(lama.speedx >= -1 && lama.speedx <=1){
        lama.speedx = 2;
    }
    lama.speedy = MathUtils.random(-5, 5);
    if(lama.speedy >= -1 && lama.speedy <=1){
        lama.speedy = 2;
    }

    Rectangle livinglama = new Rectangle();

    livinglama.x = lama.x;
    livinglama.y =  lama.y;
    livinglama.width = 64;
    livinglama.height = 64;


    lama.lamarect = livinglama;
lamas.add(lama);
    lastLamaTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}


@Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(110 / 255F, 211 / 255F, 43 / 255F, 1 / 255F);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if(spawnlama == true){
            spawnLama();
            spawnlama = false;
        }

        for (Lama lama : lamas) {
            if(lama.x <= -1000){
                lama.speedx = -lama.speedx;
            }
            else if(lama.x >= -200){
                lama.speedx = -lama.speedx;
            }

            if(lama.y <= -350){
                lama.speedy = -lama.speedy;
            } else if(lama.y >=100){
                lama.speedy = -lama.speedy;
            }

            if(lama.x == -500){
                if(lama.speedx < 0){
                    lama.speedx --;
                }
                if(lama.speedx >= 0){
                    lama.speedx++;
                }
            }
            lama.move();
        }


        if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){
            for (Lama lama : lamas) {
                Vector3 touch = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
                camera.unproject(touch);
                if(lama.lamarect.contains(touch.x, touch.y)){
                    money+=100;
                }else{
                    Gdx.app.setLogLevel(Application.LOG_DEBUG);
                    Gdx.app.debug("POSITION", "X touched: " + touch.x + " Y touched: " + touch.y);
                }
            }
        }



       batch.begin();



        for (Lama lama : lamas) {
            TextureRegion                   currentFrame;
            currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true);
            if(!currentFrame.isFlipX()) {
                if (lama.speedx >= 0) {
                    currentFrame.flip(true, false);
                }
            }else{
                if (lama.speedx < 0) {
                    currentFrame.flip(true, false);
                }
            }


            batch.draw(currentFrame, lama.x, lama.y, currentFrame
                            .getRegionWidth(), currentFrame.getRegionHeight());

        }

        elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
```

Lama class:

```
public class Lama {
    public int x, y, speedx, speedy;
    public Rectangle lamarect;
 //   float delay = 1; // seconds

    void move() {
        x += speedx;
        y += speedy;

        lamarect.x = x;
        lamarect.y = y;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gdx.input.getX` and `Gdx.input.getY` give screen coordinates and these need to be converted back to world coordinates. If you are using a camera you can use `camera.unproject(touchVector)` if you are working with a stage without a specified camera you can get the camera by `stage.getCamera()`.

If you do not have either then you have to convert it back yourself, I believe you have to flip the y coordinate first then add them to the bottom left point you are looking at in your game world. But you make your life easier by implementing a camera.

```
if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){
        Vector3 touch = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
        camera.unproject(touch);
        for (Lama lama : lamas) {
            if(lama.lamarect.contains(touch.x, touch.y)){
                money+=100;
            }else{
                Gdx.app.setLogLevel(Application.LOG_DEBUG);
                Gdx.app.debug("POSITION", "X touched: " + touch.x + " Y touched: " + touch.y);
            }
        }
    }
```

Other then that you are passing `Gdx.input.getX()` two times in the `contains` method.

Comment: Thank You! I use an orthographic camera, but this still won't work.

Comment: @AlGrande Are you using that camera's projection to draw the rectangle?

Comment: I added new relevant code. This is how I draw it: batch.draw(currentFrame, lama.x, lama.y, currentFrame
       .getRegionWidth(), currentFrame.getRegionHeight());

Comment: What does `lama.move()` do? Are you sure that updates `lama.rect` correctly? Try to log the values of the lama rect as well and compare both yourself. The corrections I made with `touch` and `camera.unproject()` will give you the correct world locations. So check if your `batch.draw(currentFrame, lama.x, lama.y, currentFrame
                            .getRegionWidth(), currentFrame.getRegionHeight());` is the same as the rectangle in that `if` statement.

Comment: Or change your draw to `draw(currentFrame, rect.getX, rect.getY, rect.getWidth, rect.getHeight);` Or the other way around and generate a rectangle for collision based upon the current x, y, width and height.

Comment: I would just create a `public Rectangle getRactangle()` method where you make sure it returns a correct rectangle. `{ rect.setBounds(x, y, width, height); return rect; }`

Comment: You sure lamarect has the same width and height as you use to draw the sprites?

Comment: I added the lama class. The clicking works now, but the llama still moves outside of the camera if I change the width and the height in spawnlama().

Comment: @AlGrande your recdtangle has 0 width and 0 height and can never contain or intersect with something.

Comment: I added  lamarect.x = x;
        lamarect.y = y; in the lama class

Comment: But the llama still moves outside of the camera if I change the width and height:  for (Lama lama : lamas) {
   if(lama.x <= -600){
    lama.speedx = -lama.speedx;
   }
   else if(lama.x >= 600){
    lama.speedx = -lama.speedx;
   }

   if(lama.y <= -300){
    lama.speedy = -lama.speedy;
   } else if(lama.y >=300){
    lama.speedy = -lama.speedy;
   }

Comment: I am not talking about positions here. I'm talking about the size of your rectangle. When it is 0 high and 0 wide it does not exist. Since if you have an apple that is 0 in size you can not prove to me that you have an apple ;).

Comment: But I set the width and the height in spawnLama(): livinglama.width = 320;
  livinglama.height = 3200/15;

Comment: Add a breakpoint at the collision statement. Check the values of your click/touch and check the values rectangle.

Comment: Depends on your IDE. It's part of debugging, it's very important to learn so you can solve these problems yourself. A breakpoint let's the code stop at that part and you can evaluate variables.